# Can't mount a cdrom in Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, data-cd

I tried mounting my cdrom in linux so i researched a little (i found articles like [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-cdrom-in-linux) or [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-cdrom-in-linux/))
But every time i enter any of the mount commands in the articles i get this error:

```
   /mnt  sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom                                                       32 ✘ 
mount: /mnt/cdrom: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

or this error:

```
    /mnt  sudo mount -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom                                                                     ✔ 
[sudo] password for customcheat: 

mount: /mnt/cdrom: can't read superblock on /dev/sr0.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

output of dmesg is here: https://pastebin.com/XSA8wEEH

here is the output for inxi:

```
    ~  inxi --optical                                                                                          127 ✘ 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.87 TiB used: 871.47 GiB (22.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WDS250G1B0B-00AS40
    size: 232.89 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST4000DM004-2CV104 size: 3.64 TiB
  Optical-1: /dev/sr0 vendor: ASUS model: DRW-24D5MT dev-links: cdrom
  Features: speed: 12 multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes
    rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram
```

I use linux daily, but Im not that experienced so can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried another disc? Does your file-manager show the device?

Comment: You can test the correct functionality of CD, CD-drive and cables simply: `sudo hd /dev/sr0 -n2048`  . This should read the first block of the CD, where the real data starts at 1024 (0x400 hex). You can hear if the CD-drive is spinning up/down while moving head.

Comment: Dmesg says there is something wrong with the CD-drive or the CD medium itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another brand of CDs(none of the CDs from that pile of 12 discs i tested when i created this question did work) and now everything works. The file manager now picks up the CD without any problem.